# Change (and fade in/out) images when hovering over links using a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate a slideshow/carousel effect I've seen on this website (scroll down past the hero banner): https://www.ktm.com

I think the background of the carousel changing once an item is hovered over looks great. This is how far I've gotten:

https://codepen.io/moy/pen/QVvMxo

Looking at the KTM example it seems overly complicated to me, maybe part of some framework? So I've tried to simplify it where I can.

I don't think my example is a million miles away but it needs some refinement. The main issue I'm having is when the 3 items are hovered over, making sure the images fade in/out rather than instantly change. Is that going to be possible with the method I'm using, updating the `img src=""` using a `data-*` attribute?

I tried adding in `.fadeIn` and `.delay` but it didn't seem to do anything.

Another issue I'm having is when you remove the mouse from the carousel after hovering over the items the text seems to flicker. It looks like it's to do with the img opacity changing as when I remove that it doesn't happen - but I haven't gotten to the bottom of that yet, so any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
$(".carousel__item").hover(function() { // Changes the .image-holder's img src to the src defined in .list a's data attribute.
  var value = $(this).attr('data-src');
  $(".carousel__bg img").attr("src", value);
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  background: #222;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.carousel__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__bg img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__item {
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33333%;
}

.carousel__content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel__title {
  transition: all .25s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel__subtitle {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel__btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .25s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel__image {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .25s;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__title {
  opacity: .25;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__image {
  opacity: 0;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__item:hover .carousel__title {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__item:hover .carousel__flag {
  display: none;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__item:hover .carousel__subtitle {
  display: block;
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__item:hover .carousel__btn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__bg">
    <img src="https://fillmurray.com/800/300">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item" data-src="https://fillmurray.com/800/500">
    <div class="carousel__content">
      <h2 class="carousel__title">Product Name #1</h2>
      <span class="carousel__flag">Featured</span>
      <h2 class="carousel__subtitle">Longer, catchy, impactful statement</h2>
      <a href="#" class="carousel__btn">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
    <img src="https://fillmurray.com/250/400" class="carousel__image" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item" data-src="https://fillmurray.com/800/400">
    <div class="carousel__content">
      <h2 class="carousel__title">Product Name #2</h2>
      <span class="carousel__flag">Featured</span>
      <h2 class="carousel__subtitle">Longer, catchy, impactful statement</h2>
      <a href="#" class="carousel__btn">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
    <img src="https://fillmurray.com/250/400" class="carousel__image" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item" data-src="https://fillmurray.com/800/300">
    <div class="carousel__content">
      <h2 class="carousel__title">Product Name #3</h2>
      <span class="carousel__flag">Featured</span>
      <h2 class="carousel__subtitle">Longer, catchy, impactful statement</h2>
      <a href="#" class="carousel__btn">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
    <img src="https://fillmurray.com/250/400" class="carousel__image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create those images with `style="display: none"` instead of replacing the image source. Then you can use jquery `$(".carousel__item").hover( showImage, hideImage )` to achieve your goal.

`$(image).show()` and `$(image).hide()` should be enough for what you want

Comment: Would a problem with that be that you're loading a lot of images on load that aren't needed? There could be 7 or 8 images in a carousel that's why I thought swapping the src would be best and it'd keep the matchup cleaner. Otherwise the page will be loading a lot of large images? I could apply a `background-image` instead if that was better or even reload the entire `img` rather than just the src - maybe that'd help with adding a fade?

Comment: If you are expecting the user to explore the carousel, preloading the image would be better as the image is already downloaded on load instead of download on hover.If the images are very large or you are concerning about the charge on network usage, you may need to do some optimization

Comment: I think it'd be better to load the image on hover when it's needed otherwise it could slow down the page if the user doesn't need the content. So maybe on hover the image is loaded, then fades in when it's ready? I'm continuing to play around with it but nothing yet. Thanks for all the input! :)